# .strings file from NSDictionary at Runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsfilemanager, nslocalizedstring

I am making a request to retrieve a dictionary of strings from a server. How can I write those string resources to a .strings file and retrieve individual entries at runtime?

I know it's possible by saving the file to Library/Application Support directory, but I'm having trouble retrieving individual entries from the file.

```
// Create directory
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"CFSSLocalizable"];

// Write strings to file - this works
NSString *strings = [myDictionary descriptionInStringsFileFormat];
BOOL fileWasCreated = [strings writeToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Localizable.strings", path] atomically:NO encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&anotherError];
```

Now I can't figure out how to read entries out of the file.

I've tried creating a new bundle:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];
```

and reading from the bundle like this:

```
NSString *string = [bundle localizedStringForKey:[key lowercaseString] value:nil table:nil];
```

But this is not returning values, it only returns key names. I'm also not convinced it is even reading the correct file because the key names it is returning are not in the file I'm specifying.

Does anyone know how I can store the contents of my dictionary in a file and then pull individual values from that file based on the key?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
// get the directory path
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *targetDirectoryPath = [paths.firstObject stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"CFSSLocalizable"];
if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:targetDirectoryPath isDirectory:&isDirectory]) {
    [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:targetDirectoryPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
}

NSString *targetFilePath = [targetDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Localizable.strings"];

// Write strings to file - this works
BOOL fileWasCreated = [strings writeToFile:targetFilePath atomically:NO encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&anotherError];

// Read file
if (fileWasCreated) {
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:targetDirectoryPath];
    NSString *value = NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(@"some key", nil, bundle, nil);
    NSLog(@"value: %@", value);
}
```